# Preserving Italian dialects

Tags: regional, resources

Is there a website or book that writes down Italian dialect words or phrases so they are not lost over time? My family speaks dialect and I would like to add their dialect to a website (if it exists) or learn about other dialects and the similarities/differences with my family's. Grazie mille!

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!

Comment: There are several books, sites, scholars and so on, since there are several dialects and, say, a speaker or a scholar of a particular dialect of Lombardy might not be knowledgeable about a dialect of Sicily. Which dialect are you interested in?

Comment: Indeed for many "dialects" there are fully fledged grammars, dictionaries and linguistic studies. The major ones even have literatures :). I don't think there is a single website that collects them all.

Comment: I am interested in adding town-level dialects that are in the Campania and Molise regions, especially as I find that there are differences between the towns and the regional dialect. I have gone back to Italy recently and there are few people left in those towns that speak the dialect.

Comment: Try with [this link: it contains few sentences in Naples language](http://www.vatrarberesh.it/biblioteca/ebooks/dettinapoletani.pdf).

Answer (score 7):

One thing you might try to do is to contact the [Comitato per la Salvaguardia dei Patrimoni Linguistici](https://patrimonilinguistici.it/) (*Committee for the safeguard of the linguistic heritages*). This is an association whose goal is to preserve and promote the usage of the regional languages of Italy (i.e. the so-called "dialects").

Their [resource page](https://patrimonilinguistici.it/risorse-utili/) contains some courses and grammars for some of the regional languages of Italy which you might find interesting.

Their contact page can be found [here](https://patrimonilinguistici.it/contatta-il-comitato/). Unfortunately their website seems to be only in Italian, but hopefully they will respond to inquiries in English.

They also seem to have a [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Patrimonilinguistici).